# Jquery "$(this)" selects only the first matched element

Tags: jquery, ajax

Please consider the following codes:

```
$(".xpand").click(function()
{
     var target = $(this).parent().parent().find(".msg");

     target.html("loading...");

     $.get(src, function(data)
     {
         target.html(data);
         $(this).addClass("rotated");
     }).error(function()
     {
         target.html("<b>Error in loading contents. Try again.</b>");
     });
 });
```

What's happening is, upon ajax success, the "rotated" class is added to ".xpand" only if the ".xpand" clicked is the first among other ".xpand".
If I chose to click the second one, the third one, or the last one, the ajax still process, but the "rotated" class is not added.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks for those who will answer :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to store `$(this)` inside another variable in order to access it inside your `$.get()` method:

```
$(".xpand").click(function () {
    var target = $(this).parent().parent().find(".msg"),
        that = $(this);

    target.html("loading...");

    $.get(src, function (data) {
        target.html(data);
        that.addClass("rotated");
    }).error(function () {
        target.html("<b>Error in loading contents. Try again.</b>");
    });
});
```

Comment: This is because the context of `this` is being lost inside the `$.get` callback.

Comment: I've already done what you have said here. But unfortunately, the problem still persist.

Anyway, Thanks @Felix :)

Answer (score 0):

```
   $(".xpand").click(function () {
       var target = $(this).parent().parent().find(".msg");

       target.html("loading...");

       var inside = this;
       $.get(src, function (data) {
           target.html(data);
           $(inside).addClass("rotated");
       }).error(function () {
           target.html("<b>Error in loading contents. Try again.</b>");
       });
   });
```

'this' in the context you are using it, refers to the request rather than the thing that issued the event. To fix this, store a copy of this before making the request.

Comment: tried your suggestion, but still doesn't work.

thanks anyway for answering, @Cas :)

Comment: target.addClass("rotated"); ?